# REST call to sslCertificate.insert fails with "The SSL certificate could not be parsed", but gcloud works fine

Tags: ssl, google-cloud-platform

Here's a example program that generates the error:

```
import urllib3
import certifi
from google.auth.transport.urllib3 import AuthorizedHttp
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import boto3
from pprint import pprint
import json

# parameters

JSON_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = "/home/mwilbert/gcp/matt-vm-service-account.json"
SCOPES = [
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute'
]

TEST_PROJECTID = 'mwilbert-workspace'
TEST_FULLCHAIN_FILE = '/etc/letsencrypt/live/fake.mapgeo.io/fullchain.pem'
TEST_PRIVKEY_FILE = '/etc/letsencrypt/live/fake.mapgeo.io/privkey.pem'

http = urllib3.PoolManager(cert_reqs='CERT_REQUIRED',ca_certs=certifi.where())
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(JSON_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE)
scoped_credentials = credentials.with_scopes(SCOPES)
authed_http = AuthorizedHttp(scoped_credentials,http)

requestBody = {
  "name":"deleteme",
  "description": "fake domain cert",
  "certificate": TEST_FULLCHAIN_FILE,
  "privateKey": TEST_PRIVKEY_FILE,
}
rb = json.dumps(requestBody)
url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/%s/global/sslCertificates' % TEST_PROJECTID
r = authed_http.urlopen('POST',
                        url,
                        headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                        body=rb)

response = json.loads(r.data)
pprint(response)
```

However if I pass the same arguments to gcloud

```
gcloud compute ssl-certificates create deleteme
--certificate=/etc/letsencrypt/live/fake.mapgeo.io/fullchain.pem
--private-key=/etc/letsencrypt/live/fake.mapgeo.io/privkey.pem
--description="fake domain cert" --project=mwilbert-workspace
```

from the same terminal session the certificate is created. The certificate is in .PEM format.

Has anyone gotten this call to work? If so, any pointers?

Comment: Edit your question and include the API `body` that you are passing to `insert()` and include your actual code, otherwise we can only guess.

Comment: Edited with additional info.

Comment: Please post the `entire` code as one, not selected pieces. We know how to read code, so breaking it up is not helpful. Please add the `body` you are posting. `"/path/to/certchain/file"` is probably not a real path and we do not like to guess if you have it correct. Add the error message that you are receiving.

Comment: The code isn't written in such a way to make that a reasonable idea. When I get a chance, I'll put together a test script that is more amenable to posting. The error message I get is in the title: "The SSL certificate could not be parsed". There is also the "reason", which is "sslCertificateCouldNotParseCert"